# Getting text from each dynamically created button in 15 Squares game (with custom input for rows and columns)

Tags: button, dynamic, text

I was wondering how I would go about **getting text from a dynamically created button** for x amount of buttons. I'm trying to create a save file where it saves

x rows
x columns
0
1
3
2
4
5

in a **vertical order, 1 number per line**, so when I load the file, it will open the **same number of rows, columns, and put the game back in that order.**

The **problem** that I'm getting is that every time I save, I get the rows and columns fine, but the button numbers, while there are the correct amount, are **always the number of the last button.**

example: 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

Here is the code where I believe I need to change something.

```
        private void randomizeButtons(Button btnRandomized, int temporaryNumber)
    {
        if (totalSquares[0] == 0)
        {
            totalSquares[0] = temporaryNumber;
            btnRandomized.Text = temporaryNumber.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            int k = 0;
            while (k < totalSquares.Length)
            {
                if (buttonCount == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (totalSquares[k] == temporaryNumber)
                {
                    temporaryNumber = random.Next(1, totalSquares.Length);
                    k = 0;

                    continue;
                }
                k++;
            }

            if (k == totalSquares.Length)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < totalSquares.Length; m++)
                {
                    if (totalSquares[m] == 0)
                    {
                        totalSquares[m] = temporaryNumber;
                        btnRandomized.Text = temporaryNumber.ToString();
                        buttonNumber = int.Parse(btnRandomized.Text);
                        buttonText = buttonNumber.ToString();

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and here is the doSave method

```
private void doSave(string fileName)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);

        writer.WriteLine(numberOfRows);
        writer.WriteLine(numberOfColumns);
        for (int lines = 0; lines < btnArray.Length; lines++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(buttonText);
        }
        writer.Close();

    }
```